# IE9 does not ask to instal flash when it's needed on a website

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, flash, ieaddon

I'm using IE9 on a Windows 7 64bit machine. For testing, i've disabled my flash add-on in IE9. I expect IE9 to ask the user to install flash when it's required.

So does firefox and chrome, but IE9 does not do this for me.

Example: I go to this site http://www.aeonflux.com/

The only thing I get to see is a black screen with a small error icon on the top left of the screen.
Here i expect IE9 to tell me that i need Flash and ask me to install it.

Does anyone knows if this is normal behavior or if there is any way I can fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally changed the code to embed the flash file using the info, provided by adobe, I found [here](http://Flash%20Professional%20Help%20/%20%20OBJECT%20tag%20syntax%20%7C%20Flash%20Professional):

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="550" height="400" id="movie_name" align="middle">
<param name="movie" value="movie_name.swf"/>
<!--[if !IE]>-->
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="movie_name.swf" width="550" height="400">
    <param name="movie" value="movie_name.swf"/>
<!--<![endif]-->
    <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash">
        <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player"/>
    </a>
<!--[if !IE]>-->
</object>
<!--<![endif]-->
```